# Why is Facebook asking me to upgrade graph when I don't make these calls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I recently changed the number in my FB.init call from 2.2 to 2.6

```
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXX', 
      cookie     : true,  
      xfbml      : true,  
      version    : 'v2.6' 
    });
```

I'm not using any of the calls in the descriptions in the image eg read_friendlists - so why is Facebook telling me I need to change something?

Also, are the numbers in the Affected Methods column version numbers, and if so, where do you find the version number in the Facebook Login sdk you have? Mine says FACEBOOK_SDK_V4

[image]

These are the methods use in php:

```
 use Facebook\FacebookSession;
 use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
 use Facebook\GraphUser;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
 use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
 use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
 use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
 use Facebook\GraphObject;
 use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
 use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
 use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Could you provide us the methods you are using and what is the exactly message from Facebook?

Comment: Thanks Jurik. Please excuse my ignorance - it's a long time since I've worked on code. Are the methods the "use Facebook" lines I just included in my question for you?

The email message I got from FB is in my next comment:

Comment: "To prepare for your app migrating to v2.1, we have released a new feature under API Version Upgrades in your app dashboard that helps you to upgrade your app before the August 8, 2016 deadline. This will prevent you from getting more notices like these, and automatically upgrades all of your app's usage to Graph API v2.1. ...

Comment: The oldest supported version of the Graph API for XXXXXXXX is v2.0, which will be deprecated on Monday, August 8, 2016. If your app has been making recent API calls against v2.0, please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid potential broken experiences.

We recommend using our new Graph API Upgrade Tool to see which of your calls are affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in newer versions. You can also use our changelog to see the full list of changes."

Comment: The image I attached to the question is the output of the Graph API Upgrade Tool

Comment: When a user authenticates with your app, you have to set a scope (permissions) that the user  'can' provide your app. How does this code look alike? Or do you configure it in Facebooks Developer backend? Maybe there are some of these mentioned permission requests.
I do not think that it has something to do with Facebooks classes - I guess you install them with composer and they are up to date.

Comment: I set it in the js code. It looks like:

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile","email"], function (response) 
  { 
   if(response.authResponse)    logFacebookUserIn(response);
   
  }, function (error) 
  {
   MSG(JSON.stringify(error),1,0,0);   
  });

Comment: Then I do not know. It is wired. But a few years ago several similar things happend to my FB apps. And their bug report system was only in a few cases helpful. Did you create a bug report there?

Comment: No - not yet - I wasn't aware it was a bug - I thought I wasn't understanding something. Thanks your the help and info.